# Putting a div on a new line (problem caused by floating <ul> elements)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

So I have a 3 unordered lists like so:

```
  <ul class="menu">
<li class="heading">Title (Click To Download)</li>
<li><a title="Download sample.mp3" href="http://example.com/sample.mp3">Sample Song</a></li>
</ul>
```

With the following css style:

```
/* SITE MAP MENUS */

ul.menu {

    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #898989;
}


ul.menu li {}

.menuText
{

}
li.heading {
    color: #493f0b;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
}
```

However when I put a new div:

```
<div class="pleasedontfloat">The paganation would go here..</div>
```

Instead of going below the lists it goes next to them. How would I fix this? (the class pleasedontfloat has no rules applied to it)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
.pleasedontfloat { 
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One of these days I'll wrap my head around this voodoo known as css.